# Undirected property path of arbitrary length between two nodes

Tags: sparql, rdf

I would like to formulate an SPARQL query that asks if there exist a undirected path between node a and d.

My data looks as follows:

```
<a> <p1> <b>
<c> <p2> <b> 
<c> <p3> <d>
```

Here is a small ascii drawing of the same data

```
(a) --> (b) <-- (c) --> (d)
```

I tried with the following query:

```
ASK   
WHERE {
  <a>  (<>|^<>)* <d> .
}
```

How do I make an ASK SPARQL query that returns yes when asked if there is an undirected path between a and d?

Comment: There is no property `<>` in your data, so how should this match. The common pattern for any edge is `<>|!<>`, i.e. p or not p for a p that does not exists in the data

Comment: `((<>|!<>)|^(<>|!<>))*` could work

Comment: My understanding is that <p1>,<p2>, and <p3> would match <>, am I misunderstanding something?  Why would I match "not p", I only want paths that exist! I tried  the pattern on my example data and it works. Would it be possible that you explain why this path solves my problem?

Comment: `<>` is not a wildcard but an entity whose URI will be resolved relative to the current base URI. There is no wildcard for property paths, but a workaround is to use a URI that does not exist in the data and then there is always a path between two nodes as either p or not p must be satisfied. This is quite obvious as the URI of a predicate can't for sure be both

Comment: @AKSW feel free to post an answer, I will accept it. Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no property `<>` in your data, so this won't match. The common pattern for "any edge" is `<>|!<>`, i.e. a property `p` or `not p` for a `p` that does not exist in the data.

`((<>|!<>)|^(<>|!<>))*` should work in your example.